# The program is showing a missing statement . Why is this error coming?

Tags: java, string, methods

```
 static String dayOfProgrammer(int year) {
        if(year==1918){
        String date= "26:08:"+year;
        return date;
        }
         if(year<1918|| year>1918){
            if(year%4==0){
                String date= "12:09:"+year;
                return date;
            }
            else{
                String date= "13:09:"+year;
                return date;
            }
        }

    }
```

> Blockquote the method accepts an integer value "year" and should return a String value "date". but due to so issue ,it showcases a runtime error of missing return statement when tested against multiple test cases.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler can not guarantee all paths return a value. Switch your statement`if(year<1918|| year>1918)` for an `else` and all paths will return:

```
static String dayOfProgrammer(int year) {
    if(year==1918){
    String date= "26:08:"+year;
    return date;
    }
    else{
        if(year%4==0){
            String date= "12:09:"+year;
            return date;
        }
        else{
            String date= "13:09:"+year;
            return date;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer from @HaroldH is correct, but I'd suggest a simpler layout.

```
static String dayOfProgrammer(int year) {
    if (year == 1918) {
        return "26:08:" + year;
    }
    else if (year%4 == 0) {
        return "12:09:" + year;
    }
    else {
        return "13:09:" + year;
    }
}
```

or even (since there's no need for the 'else' after a 'return')

```
static String dayOfProgrammer(int year) {
    if (year == 1918) {
        return "26:08:" + year;
    }
    if (year%4 == 0) {
        return "12:09:" + year;
    }
    return "13:09:" + year;
}
```

The simpler layout of these two versions makes the control-flow obvious at a glance, and you can see there is always a return executed.

The placement of 'else if (…)' on one line that does not cause further indentation emphasizes that the code is making a simple sequence of choices between alternatives.

You don't actually need the 'else' - as in the second example. I regard that choice here as a matter of taste; I think I prefer the first in this case, but there are no hard-and-fast rules; what matters is the transparency of the resulting code.

You'll note I eliminated the 'data' variables; they served no real purpose here.